# get Number of month from a date php

Tags: php, date

Suppose I have a date specific as `2016-11-14` . 
Also I have another date (starting) `02-14-2017` and ending `02-30-2017`

I want to count the months that has passed is the date `2016-11-14` until the set of Range date.

I tried searching but I cant find a link on how to find months that has passed from a date to set of range date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime()` makes doing date math easy:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2016-12-01');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2017-02-01');
$interval = $datetime2->diff($datetime1);
echo (($interval->format('%y') * 12) + $interval->format('%m'));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/bjiWv)

Comment: i need 10 mins to tick the answer :)

Comment: Or you could use `echo ($interval->y * 12 + $interval->m);`